# .htaccess Maintenance Multiple IP's

Tags: .htaccess

I am using the code below within my .htaccess file to place my site into maintenance. Essentially what it  does is to redirect anyone who is NOT from a specific IP address to a .maintenance. subdomain where I have a maintenance page up (thus allowing me to perform testing on the real site). My question is, how would I add a second IP address to the line:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^23\.254\.12\.43
```

to allow 2 IP's to come through? Is it as simple as just putting a space and using the same format as the first one? (Sorry in advance if it really IS that simple, but I haven't tested it due to fear it may appear to be working but really not). Thanks!

```
###################################################################
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^23\.254\.12\.43
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://maintenance.mysite.com [R=307,L]
####################################################################
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just adding another `RewriteCond` to handle the second IP address should be fine, like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=23.254.12.43
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=192.168.0.1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://maintenance.mysite.com [R=307,L]
```