# htaccess redirect all but 2 IP addresses

Tags: php, .htaccess

Ok So I have a testing website and a live website. I want to use my htaccess to automatically direct any vistors to the live site unless the client IP is one of 2 IPS , my home IP and my work IP.

So I can access testing.mysite.com but if any one else tries to access testing.mysite.com they should be diverted to www.mysite.com. Here is what I have so far

( this htaccess file is in my working folder for my testing site , testing.mysite.com )

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=<my ip address>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://<live website >  [R=301]
```

Now this works like a dream but when I swap offices I need to keep changing the ip address in my htacces file so I can view the the testing site.

I am trying to acheive this basically

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=<my ip address at work > ||  %{REMOTE_ADDR} != <my ip address at home >
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ <live website > [R=301]
```

But I get an error sayings server is mis configured , can any one tell how to achieve this, I know its probably something really simple but I can seem to find the answer

any help would be very welcome !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess Maintenance Multiple IP's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213529/htaccess-maintenance-multiple-ips)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think I cracked my own question, please correct me if I am wrong though or if this is not recommended but it seems I can just use 2 rewrite conditions before the rule like this

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=<my ip address at work >
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=<my ip address at home >
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://<live website >  [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

USE `[OR]`:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=<my ip address at work > [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} != <my ip address at home >
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ <live website > [R=301]
```